# VueJs - Need to increment circular progress bar percent based on each lifecylce hooks

Tags: vuetify.js, vuejs3

I need to update the Circular progress bar percent based on vuejs life cycle hooks **BeforeCreate** and **Created**. This progress bar has to stop when the record is completely created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by binding the value attribute of the circular progress bar to a variable like `:value="pBarValue"` and set your desired percentage to it at each hook like :

```
beforeCreate() {
 this.pBarValue = 0;
 }
created() {
 this.pBarValue = 100;
 }
```

and you can use `v-if` or `v-show` based on your situation, for when you want to display it and when you want to hide it.
just note that the whole process usually goes very fast and if you want to see the result you should probably use `console.log` !

Comment: Is there a way we can automatically calculate the value.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what do you mean by "automatically calculate" ?

Comment: I need to increment the circular progress bar value when it is in BeforeCreate() and need to close it whit reaches the Created() hook.

Comment: well you kinda have to set the value inside each hook, so I don't think that it could get any more automatic.

Comment: Is it possible to use settimeout to increase the value?

Comment: Yes , It is possible.

Comment: beforeCreate() {
            this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (this.uploadPercentage === 100) {
            return (this.uploadPercentage = 0)
            }
            thisuploadPercentage += 10
        }, 1000)
        }, ls this correct way?

Comment: This will add 10% to your `<v-progress-circular>` every 1 sec and if it is at 100% , resets the percentage. if this is what you wanna do , then yes , it is the correct way .

Comment: i have to make this percentage 100 only when it reaches Created() hook, how can i define it in this settimeout?

Comment: You should know that `created()` hook will work regardless and unrelated to your timeout ! so all you need to do is to just set percentage to 100 inside `created()` just like the answer shows.